# Trying to make a graph with two trendlines for data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to do a graph with two trendlines like in the following hand-drawn illustration, but this is the first time I've tried anything substantial in Excel and I can't figure out how to get anything other than a trendline that is just for all the data points in general.  How can I do this?

[image: example graph]

Comment: It's hard to tell what's driving your lines (and it shows three).  Excel will calculate and draw one trend line per data series.  The simplest way would be to add additional series based on points you want the lines to pass through.  You can always set Excel to not display data markers for the extra series.

Comment: How do you add additional series to the same graph?

Comment: I don't have immediate access to Excel to verify the actual menu choices, but basically, to do it from an existing graph, select a data point.  IIRC, right-click will give you access to "edit data series".  That will have an option to add a series.  Just specify the location of the data.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to addmore than one trend line to a graph. (Picture is of a spread sheet of my own creation.) There is a linear and polynomial trend line.

Right click on your data series (the actual line in the graph) then click on "Add Trendline". You should be able to add as many trendlines as you like.
[image: graph]